# Matlab equivalent for Python's id function

Tags: python, matlab, memory, memory-management

Does Matlab have any equivalent to Python's `id` [function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id)? I tried some Python-like syntax to create a copy of a Matlab table and was surprised that it actually created a table with a variable whose value was the table, and whose variable name was the table variable identifier.

I'm trying to get a sense of how assignment works in Matlab, whether it is by reference or creates a copy, and I'd like to get the address of the object if at all possible.

Comment: MATLAB doesn't tend to expose this type of information. You can get a high level understanding of its memory management from [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html)

Comment: Note that the address of an object can change at will, because of the lazy copying that MATLAB does (copy on write). If you share *why* you want to know the address of an object, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest to Python's `id` that I know in Matlab is the undocumented `format debug`. With this format option, typing a variable name in the command window shows information about its memory usage.

The displayed `pr` field is a pointer to the real part of the data, and `pi` is for the imaginary part. (Credit to [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) for [this information](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29474286#29474286).) Starting from Matlab R2018a, the `pi` pointer no longer exists, because of the new [interleaved complex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-support-for-interleaved-complex.html) storage.

For example, the following illustrates Matlab's [copy-on-write](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/) mechanism. Note how the statement `y = x` does not create a copy of `x` (it has the same `pr` as `y` has), but modifying an entry of `y` later on triggers the copy (`pr` changes).

```
>> format debug
>> x = 1:5;
>> y = x;
>> x, y
x =
Structure address = 37751590
m = 1
n = 5
pr = ff4bbe80
pi = 0
     1     2     3     4     5
y =
Structure address = 37751590
m = 1
n = 5
pr = ff4bbe80
pi = 0
     1     2     3     4     5

>> y(5) = 10;
>> x, y
x =    
Structure address = 37751590
m = 1
n = 5
pr = ff4bbe80
pi = 0
     1     2     3     4     5
y =    
Structure address = 37751de0
m = 1
n = 5
pr = 85c71e0
pi = 0
     1     2     3     4    10
```